# Updating/re-asking software-related questions

Tags: discussion, r, exact-duplicates, software, old-posts

In R, there are two main packages for estimating mixed effects models: [nlme](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nlme/index.html) and [lme4](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/index.html). They have certain differences. ([There are also other packages.](http://glmm.wikidot.com/pkg-comparison))

- In 2010, we had a well-received question: [How to choose nlme or lme4 R library for mixed effects models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5344/how-to-choose-nlme-or-lme4-r-library-for-mixed-effects-models)
- In 2013, we had a follow-up question ([lme and lmer comparison](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64226/lme-and-lmer-comparison)), referring to the earlier question and noting that the answer might have changed in the intervening years. (The consensus appeared to be that the earlier answers were still valid.)

Now it's 2016, and I'd be interested in whether the situation is still as in 2010/2013. (Specifically, I'm most interested in panel data as per the [2013 question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64226/lme-and-lmer-comparison), but I'm also interested in any other changes in the differences between the packages.)

Should I just ask a new question, referring to the earlier ones? Or do something different?

Comment: The problem here, as I see it, is that our standards for what is considered on-topic have gotten much stricter since then. I'm not sure the question your suggesting would be considered on-topic today.

Comment: @gung: I'd take a chance on it. I'd say the question is still on-topic, because ["it needs *statistical expertise* to understand or answer"](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). But I'd now certainly include this little argument to stave off closure, if I do post such a question.

Comment: Yeah, I recognize that. I'm OK with grandfathering in the existing questions. I honestly think it's borderline & I'm not sure which way I lean, but my impression is that others have become more hard line than I am, & I suspect people would vote to close. I am actually in the process of formulating a meta.CV Q about our close voting.

Comment: Have you thought putting a bounty on the 2013 question? There is a notice box where you can explain what you are looking for in the newer answers.

Comment: I'd be quite ok with this type of question, for essentially the reasons that @StephanKolassa cites.  Software and programming are an essential part of doing statistics and machine learning, I wish our line was a bit softer.

Comment: I think these questions, & others like them, show that software recommendations should be on topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the comments, I have set a bounty [on the 2013 question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64226/lme-and-lmer-comparison), claiming that "The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes", which is not entirely correct but the closest "bounty reason".

(Now I'd just love for [the bounty text to respect the paragraph breaks I included](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124016/line-breaks-paragraphs-for-bounty-text)...)

*Edit*: I just awarded the bounty to [Ben Bolker's original answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/64236/1352), although there was not as much updating going on as I had hoped for. However, [Ben posted a link to some additional recent thoughts of his](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64226/lme-and-lmer-comparison#comment407306_64236), which he may include in his answer at some date.

Comment: It drives me completely nuts when apps destroy my whitespace and end of lines.